# parsing "?<=Sys ).*" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use this code below. However. It gives me error.

Error:

```
parsing "?<=Sys ).*" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.
```

Code:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(line, "?<=Sys ).*").ToString
```

Sample Text:

```
G Operating Sys (Linux Redhat v6.x, Ent 64 bit (small
G Operating Sys (OS8 MS Win Svr 2012R2 EE)
```

What does the error mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the opening parenthesis in your regex lookbehind grouping:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(line, "(?<=Sys ).*").ToString()
```